# finding the order of which checkboxes have been checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, checkbox

I'm trying to get the order of which checkboxes have been checked.

```
<ul class="dropdown-content checkboxes">
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Billy</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Jacob</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Bob</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Alexandren</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Erren</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Stewgart</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Jillian</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Other</label></li>
</ul>
```

I came up with this but i'm unable to get the order of when the checkboxes were checked. I'm only able to get the list of which ones are checked only.

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    console.log($(":checked").length);
    var i = 0;
    checked = true;
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        if (this.checked == false) {
            i++;
            if (i === 8) {
                checked = false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How would I get the data of what order they were checked? for instance "Checkboxes 1, 6, 3 ,2 were checked in this order"

Comment: if a checkbox is checked, then unchecked, then checked again would you want the duplicate in the list? i.e 1,2,5,3,5

Comment: @user2950720 yes, no duplications. My apologies on not listing that. if it's unchecked it shouldn't be in the list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have keep track of what checkboxes are checked, for instance in an array

```js
var order = [];

$("[type=checkbox]").on('change', function() { // always use change event
    var idx = order.indexOf(this);
 
    if (idx !== -1) {         // if already in array
     order.splice(idx, 1); // make sure we remove it
    }

    if (this.checked) {    // if checked
     order.push(this);  // add to end of array
    }
    
    // <------------------------------------For demonstration
    $('#result').html(JSON.stringify($.map(order, function(elem) {
     return $(elem).closest('label').text().trim();
    })));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-content checkboxes">
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Billy</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Jacob</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Bob</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Alexandren</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Erren</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Stewgart</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Jillian</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Other</label></li>
</ul>
<div id="result"></div>
```

---

To get the index of each checkbox, or more accurately the parent LI, you could just map them

```
var map = $.map(order, function(elem) {
    return $(elem).closest('li').index();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3oznqqLf/1/)

Comment: If using this method to post the data in a form and processing with PHP, how would you get the order values along the associated checkbox values?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in pure JavaScript too:

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var order = [];

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'), function (checkbox) {
    'use strict';
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
        var previousLi = checkbox.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling;
        var index = 0;
        while (previousLi !== null) {
            previousLi = previousLi.previousElementSibling;
            index += 1;
        }

        if (checkbox.checked) {
            order.push(index);
        } else {
            order.splice(order.indexOf(index), 1);
        }

        result.textContent = order;
    });
});
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-content checkboxes">
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"/>Billy</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"/>Jacob</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"/>Bob</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"/>Alexandren</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"/>Erren</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"/>Stewgart</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"/>Jillian</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox"/>Other</label></li>
</ul>
<p id="result"></p>
```

In the above code, for each checkbox we invoke function, which on it's change will:

- get index of our `input`'s `li` in it's parent,
- either

  - add it at the end of an array on check, or
  - remove appropriate element of an array on uncheck, and
- present an array (for demonstration purposes).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to bind to the checkboxes being clicked, and push to an array some information corresponding to the checkboxes, then search through the array, their position would be the order in which they were checked.