# I have five 6 checkboxes in a div if i select 1 or 2 or 3 based on the first 3 id other 3 checkboxes should be disabled i mean 4,5 and 6

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five 6 checkboxes in a div and each has different ids if i select either of the first 3 based on the id the other 3 below checkboxes should be disabled
and the first 3 should be enabled

i tried in jquery to achieve this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ip-workshop-checkbox-input').on('click', function(event) {
    var countChecked = 0;
    $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).removeClass("greyed");
        $(this).css("background-color", "");
        countChecked++;
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("greyed");
      }
    });
    if (countChecked == 0) {
      $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input").removeClass("greyed");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[1]" id="workshop_QerXef50-1" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[2]" id="workshop_QerXef50-2" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[3]" id="workshop_QerXef50-3" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[4]" id="workshop_QerXef50-4" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[5]" id="workshop_QerXef50-5" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[6]" id="workshop_QerXef50-5" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
```

I have five 6 checkboxes in a div and each has different ids if i select either of the first 3 based on the id the other 3 below checkboxes should be disabled
and the first 3 should be enabled

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: there are 6 checkboxes 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 with their different ids , if i select first check box the down three i mean 4, 5, 6 should be disabled and the other 3 i mean 1,2 and 3 should be enabled

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229021/finding-the-order-of-which-checkboxes-have-been-checked . It will be useful

Comment: Actually i need based on the ids only

Comment: 1 is checked 4 is disable,2 is checked  5 is disable , 3 is checked 6 is disable, is that your concern.

Comment: no tht is dynamic actually i wil get some checkboxes based on id , i need to disable only specific checkboxes

Comment: because now i have 6 checkboxes it may 8 also sometimes , and i can capture only by ids

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hope this will help:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
      if($('#workshop_QerXef50-1').is(':checked')||$('#workshop_QerXef50-2').is(':checked') || $('#workshop_QerXef50-3').is(':checked')){
      $('#workshop_QerXef50-6,#workshop_QerXef50-5,#workshop_QerXef50-4').attr('disabled','disabled');
      }else{
      $('#workshop_QerXef50-6,#workshop_QerXef50-5,#workshop_QerXef50-4').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
      if($('#workshop_QerXef50-4').is(':checked')||$('#workshop_QerXef50-5').is(':checked') || $('#workshop_QerXef50-6').is(':checked')){
      $('#workshop_QerXef50-1,#workshop_QerXef50-2,#workshop_QerXef50-3').attr('disabled','disabled');
      }else{
      $('#workshop_QerXef50-1,#workshop_QerXef50-2,#workshop_QerXef50-3').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1: <input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[1]" data-order="1" id="workshop_QerXef50-1" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
2: <input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[2]" data-order="2" id="workshop_QerXef50-2" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
3: <input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[3]" data-order="3" id="workshop_QerXef50-3" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
4: <input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[4]" data-order="4" id="workshop_QerXef50-4" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
5: <input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[5]" data-order="5" id="workshop_QerXef50-5" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
6: <input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[6]" data-order="6" id="workshop_QerXef50-6" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
```

Comment: yes but if i select 4 or 5 or 6 then 1,2 and 3 should be disabled based on the id

Comment: and the approach what i wanted is correct , but need in the reverse way also

Comment: repeat the if else condition once , while altering the ids, plz check , I did.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution. I introduced a new attribute data-order with checkbox to recognize the checkboxes. You can recognize the checkboxes from the ID. But it is cumbersome. The following method is easiest

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ip-workshop-checkbox-input').on('click', function (event) {
                var dOrder = $(this).attr("data-order");
               
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input").prop("disabled", false);
                    if (dOrder > 3) {
                        $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input[data-order='1']").prop("disabled", true);
                        $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input[data-order='2']").prop("disabled", true);
                        $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input[data-order='3']").prop("disabled", true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input[data-order='4']").prop("disabled", true);
                        $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input[data-order='5']").prop("disabled", true);
                        $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input[data-order='6']").prop("disabled", true);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input").prop("disabled", false);

                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[1]" data-order="1" id="workshop_QerXef50-1" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[2]" data-order="2" id="workshop_QerXef50-2" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[3]" data-order="3" id="workshop_QerXef50-3" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[4]" data-order="4" id="workshop_QerXef50-4" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[5]" data-order="5" id="workshop_QerXef50-5" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[6]" data-order="6" id="workshop_QerXef50-5" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
```

**Edit**

For ID only - For your issue

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ip-workshop-checkbox-input').on('click', function (event) {
                //var dOrder = $(this).attr("data-order");
                var dOrder = $(this).attr("id").replace("workshop_QerXef50-", "");

                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input").prop("disabled", false);
                    if (dOrder > 3) {
                        $("#workshop_QerXef50-1").prop("disabled", true);
                        $("#workshop_QerXef50-2").prop("disabled", true);
                        $("#workshop_QerXef50-3").prop("disabled", true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#workshop_QerXef50-4").prop("disabled", true);
                        $("#workshop_QerXef50-5").prop("disabled", true);
                        $("#workshop_QerXef50-6").prop("disabled", true);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $(".ip-workshop-checkbox-input").prop("disabled", false);

                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[1]"  id="workshop_QerXef50-1" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[2]"  id="workshop_QerXef50-2" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[3]"  id="workshop_QerXef50-3" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[4]"  id="workshop_QerXef50-4" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[5]"  id="workshop_QerXef50-5" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="workshop_QerXef50[6]"  id="workshop_QerXef50-5" value="1" class="ip-workshop-checkbox-input">
```

Comment: can i get using the id only because i cannot alter the html so

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4w6vzku/) for you. In this fiddle I'm getting 2 values from each checkbox change `currentId` and `isChecked` and then compare them with other checkboxes. Also you had typo in your html. Your last 2 ids are the same but last should be 6. Hope this helps.

```
const $allCheckboxes = $('.ip-workshop-checkbox-input');
const halfCheckboxesCount = $allCheckboxes.length / 2;
$allCheckboxes.on('change', function(event){
    const currentId = $(this).attr('name').slice(-2,-1);
    const isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    const compare = function(index){
            return !isChecked ? false : currentId <= halfCheckboxesCount ? index >= halfCheckboxesCount : index < halfCheckboxesCount;
    };
    $allCheckboxes.each(function(index){
        $(this).toggleClass('greyed', compare(index));
      $(this).prop('disabled', compare(index))
    });
});
```

----**EDIT**----

I updated my answer based on your comments

Comment: i cannot edit the html markup that is the problem , that was by miss it should be id="workshop_QerXef50-6"

Comment: Can we reference name attr? Is it okay?

Comment: actually that data is dynamic i may be getting  now i have 6 checkboxes but i may get 8 or 10 also , and we can reference name attribute